# Добавление короткой версии параметра-справки в библиотеке click

Tags: python

Использую библиотеку click для обработки параметров запуска скрипта. 
Эта библиотека умеет самостоятельно создавать параметр `--help` для команды.

У меня возникло желание добавить возможность использования сокращённой версии команды вызова справки `-h`.

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Во всех примерах кода подразумевается, что импортирован модуль click и вызывается нужная команда, код сохранён в файле test.py.

Всего нашёл два способа добавить такую функциональность.

---

#### Использование декоратора [`@click.help_option`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.help_option)

```
@click.command()
@click.help_option('--help', '-h')
def test():
    print('Hello!')
```

В этом случае можно будет использовать как длинный, так и короткий вариант, но **оставить только короткий вариант напрямую не получится**:

```
@click.command()
@click.help_option('-h')
def test():
    print('Hello!')
```

Вывод справки будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -h      Show this message and exit.
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

Это происходит из-за того каждая команда создаёт параметр help по умолчанию. Если отключить эту возможность, то пропадёт и автоматически создаваемый длинный вариант команды, и справка будет выглядеть так, как и ожидается.

```
@click.command(add_help_option=False)
@click.help_option('-h')
def test():
    print('Hello!')
```

---

#### Использование параметра `context_settings` у декоратора [`@click.command`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.command)

```
@click.command(context_settings={'help_option_names': ['-h', '--help']})
def test():
    print('Hello!')
```

Параметр `context_settings` при передаче его в декоратор `@click.command` в конечном счёте используется в [контексте](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#context) команды.

Список `help_option_names` по умолчанию состоит из одной строки `'--help'`, если заменить этот список своим, то можно настраивать команду для вызова справки произвольным образом.

---

Источники:

- [Документация по декоратору `click.help_option`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.help_option)
- [Документация по декоратору `click.command`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.command)